# Angular Material Table with Dynamic Columns and Rows from Array

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have an array of objects and each object contains an array. Here are the models

```
export interface CarEngineCodes {
    car: string;
    engineCodes: EngineCode[];
}

export interface EngineCode {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    car: string;
    value: number;
    timeStamp: Date;
}
```

Here is an example of the data

```
{
        car: '1',
        engineCodes: [
          { id: '1', name: 'bwNBIOSStatus1', car: '1', value: 0, timeStamp: null },
          { id: '2', name: 'bwNBIOSStatus2', car: '1', value: 0, timeStamp: null },
          { id: '3', name: 'bwNBIOSStatus3', car: '1', value: 0, timeStamp: null },
          { id: '4', name: 'bwNBIOSStatus4', car: '1', value: 0, timeStamp: null },
          { id: '5', name: 'bwNAPPStatus1', car: '1', value: 0, timeStamp: null },
          { id: '6', name: 'bwNAPPStatus2', car: '1', value: 0, timeStamp: null },
        ]
      },
      {
        car: '2',
        engineCodes: [
          { id: '7', name: 'bwNBIOSStatus1', car: '2', value: 0, timeStamp: null },
          { id: '8', name: 'bwNBIOSStatus2', car: '2', value: 0, timeStamp: null },
          { id: '9', name: 'bwNBIOSStatus3', car: '2', value: 0, timeStamp: null },
          { id: '10', name: 'bwNBIOSStatus4', car: '2', value: 0, timeStamp: null },
          { id: '11', name: 'bwNAPPStatus1', car: '2', value: 0, timeStamp: null },
          { id: '12', name: 'bwNAPPStatus2', car: '2', value: 0, timeStamp: null },
        ]
      },
      {
        car: '3',
        engineCodes: [
          { id: '13', name: 'bwNBIOSStatus1', car: '3', value: 0, timeStamp: null },
          { id: '14', name: 'bwNBIOSStatus2', car: '3', value: 0, timeStamp: null },
          { id: '15', name: 'bwNBIOSStatus3', car: '3', value: 0, timeStamp: null },
          { id: '16', name: 'bwNBIOSStatus4', car: '3', value: 0, timeStamp: null },
          { id: '17', name: 'bwNAPPStatus1', car: '3', value: 0, timeStamp: null },
          { id: '18', name: 'bwNAPPStatus2', car: '3', value: 0, timeStamp: null },
        ]
      }
    ];
```

I am wanting to make a table that displays like the following

```
| engineCode     | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| -------------- | - | - | - |
| bwNBIOSStatus1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| bwNBIOSStatus2 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
```

Where each column is the Car# and each row is the EngineCode where the cell is the Value of that EngineCode

I would like to use a Mat-Table to do so.  Here is my TS

```
this.groupedEngineCodes = [
      {
        car: '1',
        engineCodes: [
          { id: '1', name: 'bwNBIOSStatus1', car: '1', value: 0, timeStamp: null },
          { id: '2', name: 'bwNBIOSStatus2', car: '1', value: 0, timeStamp: null },
          { id: '3', name: 'bwNBIOSStatus3', car: '1', value: 0, timeStamp: null },
          { id: '4', name: 'bwNBIOSStatus4', car: '1', value: 0, timeStamp: null },
          { id: '5', name: 'bwNAPPStatus1', car: '1', value: 0, timeStamp: null },
          { id: '6', name: 'bwNAPPStatus2', car: '1', value: 0, timeStamp: null },
        ]
      },
      {
        car: '2',
        engineCodes: [
          { id: '7', name: 'bwNBIOSStatus1', car: '2', value: 0, timeStamp: null },
          { id: '8', name: 'bwNBIOSStatus2', car: '2', value: 0, timeStamp: null },
          { id: '9', name: 'bwNBIOSStatus3', car: '2', value: 0, timeStamp: null },
          { id: '10', name: 'bwNBIOSStatus4', car: '2', value: 0, timeStamp: null },
          { id: '11', name: 'bwNAPPStatus1', car: '2', value: 0, timeStamp: null },
          { id: '12', name: 'bwNAPPStatus2', car: '2', value: 0, timeStamp: null },
        ]
      },
      {
        car: '3',
        engineCodes: [
          { id: '13', name: 'bwNBIOSStatus1', car: '3', value: 0, timeStamp: null },
          { id: '14', name: 'bwNBIOSStatus2', car: '3', value: 0, timeStamp: null },
          { id: '15', name: 'bwNBIOSStatus3', car: '3', value: 0, timeStamp: null },
          { id: '16', name: 'bwNBIOSStatus4', car: '3', value: 0, timeStamp: null },
          { id: '17', name: 'bwNAPPStatus1', car: '3', value: 0, timeStamp: null },
          { id: '18', name: 'bwNAPPStatus2', car: '3', value: 0, timeStamp: null },
        ]
      }
    ];

    this.displayedColumns = this.groupedEngineCodes.map(c => c.car);

    this.engineCodes = [
      { id: '1', name: 'bwNBIOSStatus1', car: '1', value: 0, timeStamp: null },
      { id: '2', name: 'bwNBIOSStatus2', car: '1', value: 0, timeStamp: null },
      { id: '3', name: 'bwNBIOSStatus3', car: '1', value: 0, timeStamp: null },
      { id: '4', name: 'bwNBIOSStatus4', car: '1', value: 0, timeStamp: null },
      { id: '5', name: 'bwNAPPStatus1', car: '1', value: 0, timeStamp: null },
      { id: '6', name: 'bwNAPPStatus2', car: '1', value: 0, timeStamp: null },
      { id: '7', name: 'bwNBIOSStatus1', car: '2', value: 0, timeStamp: null },
      { id: '8', name: 'bwNBIOSStatus2', car: '2', value: 0, timeStamp: null },
      { id: '9', name: 'bwNBIOSStatus3', car: '2', value: 0, timeStamp: null },
      { id: '10', name: 'bwNBIOSStatus4', car: '2', value: 0, timeStamp: null },
      { id: '11', name: 'bwNAPPStatus1', car: '2', value: 0, timeStamp: null },
      { id: '12', name: 'bwNAPPStatus2', car: '2', value: 0, timeStamp: null },
      { id: '13', name: 'bwNBIOSStatus1', car: '3', value: 0, timeStamp: null },
      { id: '14', name: 'bwNBIOSStatus2', car: '3', value: 0, timeStamp: null },
      { id: '15', name: 'bwNBIOSStatus3', car: '3', value: 0, timeStamp: null },
      { id: '16', name: 'bwNBIOSStatus4', car: '3', value: 0, timeStamp: null },
      { id: '17', name: 'bwNAPPStatus1', car: '3', value: 0, timeStamp: null },
      { id: '18', name: 'bwNAPPStatus2', car: '3', value: 0, timeStamp: null },
    ]
```

Here is my Table on my html

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="groupedEngineCodes" class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let group of groupedEngineCodes" matColumnDef="{{group.car}}">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
            {{group.car}}
        </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> 
            {{element.car}}
        </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

This is what that outputs.  Obviously im not correct... the columns are ok but the rows are not.

[image]